# Help in Better contour plot

Tags: plotting, special-functions

In the following piece of code, I am trying to plot a function: `fun[x,y]` for some set of given parameters. but on the y axis of contour plot, after $\pm 4.5$, curves turn abruptly, without following the continuation. In there any way to make the curve smooth following the trend of continuation ?

```
a = 8;v1 = 5; q = Sqrt[I*v1]*a;
k1[e_] := Sqrt[-e - I*v1]*a;
k2[e_] := Sqrt[-e + I*v1]*a;
dbesi[e_, z_] = D[BesselI[k1[e], z], z];
dbesj[e_, z_] = D[BesselJ[k2[e], z], z];
fun[e_] := BesselJ[k2[e], q]*dbesi[e, q] + dbesj[e, q]*BesselI[k1[e], q];
sun[x_, y_] := fun[x + I*y];
rsun[x_, y_] := Re[sun[x, y]];
isun[x_, y_] := Im[sun[x, y]];
p1 = ContourPlot[{rsun[x, y] == 0, isun[x, y] == 0}, {x, 0,  8}, {y, -6, 6}, MaxRecursion -> 5, PlotPoints -> 300, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: I believe that it is a precision problem and that you need to specify a `WorkingPrecision`. For example, `p1 = ContourPlot[
  {rsun[x, y] == 0, isun[x, y] == 0},
  {x, 0, 8}, {y, -6, 6},
  MaxRecursion -> 5,
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  Exclusions -> None,
  WorkingPrecision -> 10]` Note that you can reduce the number of `PlotPoints`

Comment: @BobHanlon Didn't help.